# PostgreSQL: Select string_agg into variable

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-sql

I have a string to execute with the string aggregate function within the postgresql function. Here is the following script for that.

**Example**:

```
create or replace function f(colvalue int,colnvalue varchar)
returns void as
$$
declare
      sql varchar;
      var varchar;
begin
     sql := 'Select var:= string_agg(................) /* Error occurred here near var:= */
             from tablename where cola ='|| colvalue || ' AND coln ='|| colnvalue;

     raise notice '%'sql;

     execute sql into var;

     raise notice var;

end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

**Error**:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":="
```

**Note**: I want the result of `string_agg` into `var`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic SQL can contains SQL statement only - but ":=" is a PL/pgSQL statement. Next, it is clean from your example, so it is useless there. Second issue is a SQL injection vulnerability (still this code should not work). Newer use a patter  `' || varcharvar || '`  for SQL used in dynamic SQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f(colvalue int,colnvalue varchar)
RETURNS void AS $$
DECLARE
  sql varchar;
  var varchar;
BEGIN
  sql := 'SELECT string_agg(..) FROM tablename WHERE cola=$1 AND coln=$2';
  RAISE NOTICE '%', sql;
  EXECUTE sql INTO var USING colvalue, colnvalue;
  RAISE NOTICE '%', var;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But getting `<NULL>` string in `var` variable. :(

Comment: Yeah! I Solved it. Thank you so much for your valuable assistance.